# How to Update a column by getting the column name dynamically from another table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

```
 create table #tableA
(
    Id int,
    ColumnName1 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName2 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName3 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName4 nvarchar(50) 
) 
 create table #tableB
(
    Id int,
    UpdateColumn nvarchar(50),
    UpdateValue nvarchar(50)
) 

Insert Into #tableA values (1,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4')
Insert Into #tableA values (2,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4')
Insert Into #tableA values (3,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4')
Insert Into #tableA values (4,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4')

Insert Into #tableB values (1,'ColumnName4','Column4Value')
Insert Into #tableB values (2,'ColumnName1','Column1Value') 

declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
set @Sql='Update a set {The column should be the value from b.UpdateColumn}={b.UpdateValue} from #tableA a join #tableB b on a.Id=b.Id'

print @Sql
exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

I need to update #tableA column dynamically based on from #tableB value.

I tried to build a dynamic sql by concatenating the value from the join clause but nothing worked.

Please suggest.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: looping through #tableb and forming a dynamic update script will do however using loops is at your discretion.

Comment: I did that earlier and working fine but the performance will not be that such great...

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using dynamic SQL (although you could).  Assuming you have only one update per id, use `case`:

```
update a
    set ColumnName1 = (case when b.UpdateColumn = 'ColumnName1' then b.UpdateValue else ColumnName1 end),
        ColumnName2 = (case when b.UpdateColumn = 'ColumnName2' then b.UpdateValue else ColumnName2 end),
        ColumnName3 = (case when b.UpdateColumn = 'ColumnName3' then b.UpdateValue else ColumnName3 end),
        ColumnName4 = (case when b.UpdateColumn = 'ColumnName4' then b.UpdateValue else ColumnName4 end)
    from #tableA a join
         #tableB b
         on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: I can do that but the actual table has more columns and every time it will update the unnecessary columns also, and I have to update around 10000 rows every time. What will be the performance of that query?

Comment: @KousiK . . . The overhead on an update is based on updating a *row*.  Multiple columns add a little bit of overhead, but the difference may not even be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate one `update` statement from your reference tables, you can use `stuff` and `for xml` to concatenate all your operations into one string value:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tableA') is not null
drop table #tableA;
if object_id('tempdb..#tableB') is not null
drop table #tableB;

create table #tableA
(
    Id int,
    ColumnName1 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName2 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName3 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName4 nvarchar(50) 
);
insert Into #tableA values (1,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4'),(2,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4'),(3,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4'),(4,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4');

create table #tableB
(
    Id int,
    UpdateColumn nvarchar(50),
    UpdateValue nvarchar(50)
);
insert Into #tableB values (1,'ColumnName4','Column4Value'),(1,'ColumnName3','Column3Value'),(2,'ColumnName1','Column1Value');

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
with c as
(
select distinct id
                ,stuff((select char(10) + '   ,' + UpdateColumn + ' = ''' + UpdateValue + ''''
                        from #tableB
                        where id = b.id
                        for xml path('')
                        ),1,5,'') as Cols
from #tableB b
)
select @sql = stuff((select ';update #tableA set'
                            + char(10)
                            + '    ' + c.Cols
                            + char(10)
                            + 'where id = ' + cast(c.id as nvarchar(10))
                            + char(10)
                            + char(10)
                from c
                for xml path('')
                ),1,1,'')

print @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Which outputs and executes the following script:

```
update #tableA set
    ColumnName4 = 'Column4Value'
   ,ColumnName3 = 'Column3Value'
where id = 1

;update #tableA set
    ColumnName1 = 'Column1Value'
where id = 2
```

Comment: Its working but the join condition is not maintaining. It Updating all rows but I need to filter that using that join clause..

Comment: @KousiK Ah, sorry I misunderstood your requirement.  I have updated the script.

Comment: ,ColumnName4 the commas is causing the issue, removed it from + '   ,' + b.UpdateColumn and it worked, but tell me one thing if there is 10000 of rows the the nvarchar(max) length will exceeded then what will be solution?

Comment: @KousiK  Yes, as I said, that version wasn't working.  I have updated it again and you should be getting the script your need.  Regarding exceeding the limit of your `nvarchar(max)` variable, it can hold over a billion characters, so I do not think this will be a problem for you.

Comment: @KousiK  Then you have done something wrong in applying my script as there is no object called `a` anywhere in my script, which runs without issue on my machine as is.

Comment: You used update a in your script but there is no such object as you have't mentioned the actual table name but used the alias a..

Comment: @KousiK  There you go, you know how to fix the script yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName ON [dbo].[tableB] 
AFTER Update
AS
Begin
--Update tableA here
End
```

Now every time tableB updated this trigger will be called and you can use any condition within it.

Comment: Can't use trigger these are all temporary tables dynamically generated inside a store procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists #tableA;
drop table if exists #tableB;

create table #tableA
(
    Id int,
    ColumnName1 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName2 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName3 nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName4 nvarchar(50) 
) 
 create table #tableB
(
    Id int,
    UpdateColumn nvarchar(50),
    UpdateValue nvarchar(50)
) 

Insert Into #tableA values (1,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4')
Insert Into #tableA values (2,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4')
Insert Into #tableA values (3,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4')
Insert Into #tableA values (4,'Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4')

Insert Into #tableB values (1,'ColumnName4','Column4Value')
Insert Into #tableB values (2,'ColumnName1','Column1Value') 

declare @Sql nvarchar(max)

select
    @SQL = string_agg('update a
    set
        ' + b.UpdateColumn +  ' = ''' + b.UpdateValue + '''
    from #tableA a', ';')
from #tableB b

print @Sql
exec sp_executesql @Sql

select
*
from #tableA
```

Comment: "string_agg" is this a built in function?

Comment: @KousiK, yes it is, from SQL Server 2017. If you are not on SQL Server 2017 (what are you waiting for :-)) you can use Micsosoft.StringUtilities CLR to create Concatenate aggregate function. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-aggregate-transact-sql)